# Why are not the fontawesome icons shown in this angular component?

Tags: angular, icons

I have a component where I use the same icon and it shows normal, while in this component the icon is not shown, only a box with the icon code is shown. in the browser console does not show any error and the request to the cdn is specified successfully, someone has any idea why not show them? Here is the code:

```html
        <div class="row mt-4">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <p class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bath fa-2x"> </i> <br> Cubículos: {{inmueble.cubiculoLocal}} <p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
            <p class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-hot-tub fa-2x"></i> <br> Area del Local: {{inmueble.areaLocal}} <p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
            <p class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bed fa-2x "></i> <br> Altura del Local: {{inmueble.alturaLocal}} <p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
            <p class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bed fa-2x "></i> <br> Fondo de Comercio: {{inmueble.fondoComercioLocal}} <p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the fontawesome module imported by your component?

Comment: I am working with cdn, however install fontawesome with npm, import the module in the app.module.ts and it does not work, but in the other component yes, that is what I do not understand. and they are written identically, copy and paste the icon code and it does not work.

Comment: So you are importing `FontawesomeModule` in `app.module.ts` ? Where are you declaring the component with the broken icons?

Comment: the components are imported into the app.module.ts

Comment: Of course they are imported in the appModule, you would have way more errors if they weren't but I'm talking about declaration, it's not the same thing :-)

Comment: [Angular Fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome)
Please check this out

Answer (score 0):

You should add the font-awesome `CSS` to styles inside the `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./node_modules/@fontawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
],
```

If you're using the CDN, import the stylesheet to your index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

**EDIT:** Also please check to ensure that you haven't inadvertently changed the font family where you want to use icons. If you have changed the `.fa` item's font family from: `FontAwesome` the icon will not show.

Comment: with the link that you gave me, it does not load anything, this is the one I use: <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity = "sha384-oS3vJWv + 0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW + Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq / 1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin = "anonymous"> and it shows me the icons in the other component, but in this component that I place here does not work.

Comment: @JulianProg, You do not have to include it in each component, just adding it to your index.html will work fine.

Comment: Yes, correct, I only added it in the index.html but it does not work.

Comment: I found the error, I had this line in the .css file: * {
font-family: helvetica;
}, said line had it so that all the words had the helvetica font, I do not understand why that line influences in which the icons are not seen, you will know which is the reason?

Comment: Yes, so your app's CSS was  overriding the font-awesome `font-family` because of which icon's didn't show up.